# Multiple not exists in MYSQL to check count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make this query work, here is my logic , I am trying to select record thats there is not at LEAST NOT one of these options:

```
1). status = Approved AND end_date >now
2). status =Approved AND end_date is NULL
3). status = Pending And end_date is NULL & COUNT(id) =1
4). status =Pending AND end_date >now & COUNT(id) =1
5). status =Pending AND end_date <now & COUNT(id) =1
```

how to accomplish this , this is what I have so far I am not sure how to check for COUNT(id) = 1 in conditions 3, 4, and 5?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    outreach
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            outreach_links
        WHERE
            outreach_links.outreach_id = outreach.id
        AND STATUS = "Approved"
        AND end_date > now()
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        outreach_links
    WHERE
        outreach_links.outreach_id = outreach.id
    AND STATUS = "Approved"
    AND end_date IS NULL
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        outreach_links
    WHERE
        outreach_links.outreach_id = outreach.id
    AND STATUS = "Pending"
    AND end_date > now()
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        outreach_links
    WHERE
        outreach_links.outreach_id = outreach.id
    AND STATUS = "Pending"
    AND end_date IS NULL
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        outreach_links
    WHERE
        outreach_links.outreach_id = outreach.id
    AND STATUS = "Pending"
    AND end_date < now()
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    o.*,
    SUM(if(ol.status = "Approved" and (ol.end_date > now() or end_date is null), 1, 0)) as cond1,
    SUM(if(ol.status = "Pending" and (ol.end_date != now() or end_date is null), 1, 0)) as cond2
from
    outreach o
left join 
    outreach_links ol on ol.outreach_id = o.id
group by
    o.id
having
    cond1 = 0 and cond2 != 1
;
```

Not sure if that's you are looking for, but you can try it.
cond2 != 1 makes your COUNT(id) = 1 condition (if there are more than one linked id in outreach_links cond2 will be greater than 1)

Comment: wuar is !=now ? I don't have that condition I have > or less or null

Comment: because 4) >now, 5) <now and 3) not null. That gives us != now ...l

Comment: I got it to work but my question if I want to select ol.cost from the MAX(ol.end_date) , how can I do that ?

Comment: I want to not only return o.* but also return ol.* ( which got the highest (end_date) ) can I do that?

Comment: With a bit hacky technic - yes. You can select max(end_date), t.cost, t.whatever you have from (select o.*, ol.* , <query in the answer>) as t group by t.end_date and add order by ol.end_date to the inner query. In that case you'll have the row associated with max(end_date)

Comment: can you modify the answe?